# Como salvar uma imagem e guardar no localStorage?

Tags: javascript, react

```
const curFiles = input.files;
for (const file of curFiles) {
    if (validFileType(file)) {
        const image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        image.classList.add('profile');
        document.querySelector('.img').appendChild(image);
    }
}
```

Eu usei o JS para pegar um arquivo pelo `input[type="file"]` e criar uma imagem no site. Mas como posso fazer para salvá-la pra todas as vezes que ele foi aberto ela continuar lá?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Para salvar itens no local storage, você precisa utilizar:

```
localStorage.setItem("nomeDaChave", image);
```

Para recuperar este item:

```
localStorage.getItem("nomeDaChave");
```

Para remover:

```
localStorage.removeItem("nomeDaChave");
```

E caso queira limpar tudo o que existe no local storage:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: eu usei isso já, salvando o blob criado da primeira vez. Mas quando o site abre novamente ele não cria a mesma imagem.